# How to use double for loop for 2 dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I'm new to C and having trouble with pointers and 2D arrays. I have a file that I want to read values from and insert them into a 2D array. the file is formatted such that the first 2 digits are the number of rows and columns respectively, and the rest of the digits on the line fill up the matrix. Currently it reads the row and column values fine, and the first row of digits, but doesn't continue after that. What's going wrong? I'm assuming I screwed up something with pointers, or I am missing something in my understanding of 2D arrays in C.

Code:

```
#define MAXSIZE 10
FILE *fpin
..

int RdRowSize()
{
    int row = 0;
    fscanf(fpin, "%d", &row);
    return row;
}

int RdColumnSize()
{
    int col = 0;
    fscanf(fpin, "%d", &col);
    return col;
}

void RdMatrix(int *row, int *col, int matrix[][MAXSIZE])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    *row = RdRowSize();
    *col = RdColumnSize();
    for(i ; i < *row ; i++) {
        for(j ; j < *col ; j++) {
            fscanf(fpin, "%d", &matrix[i][j]); /* this stops after i = 0 for some reason? */
        }
    }
}

void PrMatrix(int row, int col, int matrix[][MAXSIZE])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i ; i < row ; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout,"     ");
        for (j ; j < col ; j++) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%5d  ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}

int main()
{
    int A[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
    int rowA = 0, columnA = 0;
    RdMatrix(&rowA, &columnA, A);
    PrMatrix(rowA, columnA, A);
    ..
}
```

The contents of fpin:

```
3 3 0 6 4 2 2 5 4 5 0
```

Which should read rowA = 3, rowB = 3 (which it does) then fill the matrix with the rest of the numbers, but it stops after the first row. When I print the matrix I get this:

```
**** MATRIX **** Size = 3 x 3
0 6 4
```

Comment: Please include your print code.

Comment: I edited that in, sorry, forgot it the first time.

Comment: What does it mean "stops" ?

Comment: I have another question. Using the same setup I have here, I want to loop this for multiple matrices in the fpin FILE, but I don't know how to tell when its at the end of the file. (each matrix has its own line)

Comment: @Xzar as you written dimensions of matrix in file also give information about how many matrices to read from file

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I can't modify the file. I did figure out a mickey mouse way of doing it though. I just looped as long as `rowA > 0`. EDIT: well... it sorta works. It hangs after looping through all the matrices..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your inner for loop never repeats itself, since you don't reset j to 0.

```
for(i=0 ; i < *row ; i++) {
    for(j=0 ; j < *col ; j++) {
        fscanf(fpin, "%d", &matrix[i][j]); /* this stops after i = 0 for some reason? */
    }
}
```

This should fix the problem, and allow the latter rows to work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set back `j` to zero in your inner loop

`for(j = 0 ; j < *col ; j++) {`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the initialization of j. You need to init j to zero every time the j loop is started.

```
for (j = 0 ; j < *col ; j++)
```

Would do the trick.